# Lowest sum of 2 sets of number pairs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I am given a set of unique integers $n$.

I need to compute the smallest sum $s$ such that there are two different pairs of integers $(x1, x2)$ and $(y1, y2)$ where $x1 < x2$ and $y1 < y2$ and $x1 + x2 = y1 + y2 = s$

My solution just included iterating through in pairs and checking the sums. I tried to optimize my solution by sorting the numbers first which decreased the number of iterations but the cost of sorting made it even worse.

What is the best way to go about this?

Example: if I have the numbers 2 4 8 1 3 5. The lowest sum s would be 5 because (x1, x2) would be (1, 4) and (y1, y2) would be (2, 3).

Comment: Ogen, I'm afraid your question is not clear enough. You might consider editting it.